# Integral points inside a circle of radius r and centre at origin

Tags: calculus

Let $f(r)$ be the number of integral points inside a circle of radius $r$ and center at the origin (an integral point is a point both of whose coordinates are integers). Then $\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{f(r)}{r^2}$ is equal to

(A) $1$

(B) $\pi$

(C) $2\pi$

(D) $\pi/2$

I could not find a general formula to estimate number of points. Any ideas ?

Comment: Ya the image us such a monster!!!

Comment: Relate the number of points to the area of the circle.

Comment: I know.Cant fix it

Comment: @Yves Daoust how ?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: your duty to find out.

Comment: It's anyways my duty only.If only someone guided me...

Comment: I am getting it as $4$ the integral

Comment: Think of each point as the centre of a square side 1. The squares cover the circle (with a slight error round the perimeter). So that gives you an estimate.

Comment: With an estimate i see points follow $3,5,7$ and first few numbers of points with integers are $1,5,13,29...$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: are you solving a different problem ? The solution is obviously $\pi r^2/r^2$. (This is known as the Gauss' circle problem.)

Comment: Oh yeah i saw on mathworld lemme delete my comment

Answer (score 0):

Any lattice point $(j,k)\in{\mathbb Z}^2$ is the center of a square
$$Q_{jk}:=\left\{(x,y)\>\biggm|\>j-{1\over2}\leq x\leq j+{1\over2}, \ k-{1\over2}\leq y\leq k+{1\over2}\right\}$$
of area $1$, and different such squares have at most an edge in common. It follows that the area of a union of different such squares is equal to the number of the occurring squares.

Let an $r>1$ be given, and let $$L_r:=\bigl\{(j,k)\>\bigm|\> (j,k)\in B_r\bigr\}$$
be the set of lattice points contained in the closed disk of radius $r$ centered at $(0,0)$. Then the number $\#L_r$ of elements in $L_r$ satisfies 
$$\#L_r={\rm area}\left(\bigcup_{(j,k)\in L_r}Q_{jk}\right)\leq\pi\left(r+{1\over\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\ ,$$
since all $Q_{jk}$ involved here fit into a disk of radius $r+{1\over\sqrt{2}}$. On the other hand,
$$\#L_r={\rm area}\left(\bigcup_{(j,k)\in L_r}Q_{jk}\right)\geq\pi\left(r-{1\over\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\ ,$$
since the same $Q_{jk}$ cover at least the disk of radius $r-{1\over\sqrt{2}}$. The squeeze theorem then shows that in fact
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}{\#L_r\over r^2}=\pi \ ,$$
hence answer (B) is correct.

By the way: Finding the optimal error estimate for the approximation $\#L_r\doteq \pi r^2$ is one of the most famous (unsolved) problems in geometric number theory.

Comment: Sir,thanks for the answer.But the notations seem very weird.What is #L and that Q ? I'm not familiar with such notations ..

Comment: Avoid the word "weird" if you are not familiar with some mathematical notation.